# Method works if called from one Class but not from another

Tags: java, methods, reference

I am new to Java. I am working on a GUI for Serial Communication between a PC and a Microcontroller. I am using the RXTX Library and it works.

As i want to be able to modify the GUI from another Classes, i built the Programm as follows:

1:
    Main Class: ( Constructor not being used )

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

Draw panel = new Draw(this);
Code c = new Code(this);
Serial s = new Serial(this);
RxTx r = new RxTx(this);
JTextArea logger;
...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
GUI frame = new GUI();
frame.create();

         }
    });
public void create(){
...
//builds the GUI
   }
}
```

2:
    Serial Class:

```
public class Serial implements Runnable{

private GUI j;

public Serial(GUI j){
this.j = j;
}
...
...

public void sendSerial(String message)
{
portName = port;
j.logger.append("Serial Tx Rx Active."); //nullpointerexception here if called from rxtx                            

if (serialPortOpen != true)
return;
try {
      j.logger.append("-");
      outputStream.write(message.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) {
      j.logger.append("Error while Sending\n");
      }
   }
}
```

3:
    RxTx Class:

```
public class RxTx {

private GUI g;
private Serial sl;
String msg = new String("TEST");

public RxTx(GUI g){
    this.g = g;
}
...
...

public void foo(){

    ...
    ...
    sl.sendSerial(msg);
   }
}
```

The Problem is if i call the `sendSerial` Method from GUI Class using `s.sendSerial("TEST");`, it works perfectly, but if i call it from RxTx Class using `sl.sendSerial(msg)`, it gives me a nullpointerexceprion at line `j.logger.append("Serial Tx Rx Active.");` I tried passing String Variabels and written Text from `RxTx` to `Serial` it just never works. It always gives me a nullpointerexception in the j.logger.append line!!! If i comment that line out, it still doesn't work. In that Case absolutely nothing happens. No errors no nothing. The Serial TX doesn't work also in that case. The appending and serial Communication only works if i call the Method from the Main Class. But i need to call it from RxTx Class.

So why is it, that everything works fine if i call the Method from the Main Class but all hell breaks loose if call the Method in Serial Class from RxTx Class. Can you guys please help me resolving the issue?

Thank You

Comment: Where do you initialize `JTextArea logger`? It's getting a `null` value when the `GUI` is constructed initially. Could you initialize it right where the variable is declared?

Comment: where do you set `sl`?

Comment: @Mick: I initialize logger in create(). It is definitely being initialized before i access it. I also tried declaring and initializing at once but still the same error!!!

Comment: You will get better answers if you post complete (runnable) code and don't clip out parts that are likely important for solving the problem at hand. Also, the actual stack trace is valuable for debugging.

Comment: I understand but the Code is HUGE! It consists of 5 files in a package. Everything was going fine until i wanted to call a Method in Serial from RxTx so i thought i must have done something wrong while creating the obejects in the beginning, so that is why i just posted that. I will edit my post with more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `private Serial sl` is just not initialized.
Try

```
public RxTx(GUI g){
    this.g = g;
    this.sl = new Serial(g);
}
```

Comment: thanks andrii. this solved the nullpointerexception problem. `logger` is now being appended from `RxTx`'s Method Call. Thank You very much. You are my Hero =)

Comment: @Zombievirus where do you check your `String`?

Comment: sorry for confusing you andrii. that was my mistake. The String is being passed normally. Everything is good now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: is this concept called Reflection?? i used this way of creating objects to avoid using static objects. was i correct with my decision?

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that both declarations of `Serial` variable are differents, I mean, in one of them you use the constructor of the class `Serial` and in the other one you just use a private statement so in the first one you make reference to the class `Serial` but in the second one not.

Try to change

```
private Serial sl;
```

to

```
Serial sl = new Serial(this);
```

I expect it will fix your error.

Comment: `j` is local to Serial and `sl` is local to `RxTx`. Shouldn't that work?? If not, i have absolutely no clue, how to correct it!

Comment: I'm also new in Java and correct me if I'm wrong but... I think you have to use a constructor also in the class RxTx to the variable of type Serial.

Comment: I tried changing it to `Serial sl = new Serial(this);`. I get this error: `The constructor Serial(RxTx) is undefined`. The Constructor of Serial is `Serial(GUI)`. `this` refers to RxTx

Comment: Try to change your String to this: String msg = "TEST";